# How to check the header being sent out with a python request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Here is the code I am using:

```
def get_tor_session():
    os.startfile(r"C:\Users\Downloads\tor-win32-0.2.9.9\Tor\tor.exe")

    session = requests.session()
    # Tor uses the 9050 port as the default socks port
    session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
                   'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}
    return session

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/companyTracker/mtOptionKeys.jsp?companySymbol=ACC&indexSymbol=NIFTY&series=EQ&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-'

session = get_tor_session()    
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1)      AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
raw_page = session.get(url, headers=headers).text
```

I keep getting a: 403 forbidden response from the url.
When I make a `get` request without tor, there is no problem.

I tried:

```
>>>print(session.headers)

 {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.10.0', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

Trying to figure out if the `headers` added above is the one being sent out or the one that was `printed` with the command at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access to `sent_request.request.headers`:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.url.foo')
print(r.request.headers)
```

Output:

```
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see the headers now. Seems to be working but somehow the page allows me to access it if I go with normal headers. If I try with the above code, irrespective of headers, it gives me a access denied.